# Optimise a nested for-each loop for units on Cartesian plane

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, dictionary

A game has a large number of unit objects held in an array.

These units have x/y coordinates locating them on a 2d map.

```
let units = [
    {id: 1, x=3450, y = 1456},
    {id: 2, x=5560, y = 2423},
    {id: 3, x=1321, y = 3451}
]
```

Approx 50 times a second the game requires each unit to generate a list of other units within a given distance (to interact with them by fighting/avoiding etc).

As the unit count grows into the thousands the current process where each unit checks distance vs each other unit slows down dramatically as you start getting exponentially more tests required.

Looking into similar problems posted online we started grouping the units into row/column cell collections then only performing the distance tests on those that 'might' be close enough to be relevant. However we found that constructing this grouping actually takes longer to build and maintain than the gains it provided.

A testable version of the current code is below - on my fairly typical browser this takes about a second to complete and it needs to improve this substantially - suggestions for optimisations welcome.

```js
//create the world
let mapWidth = 5000;
let mapHeight = 2000;
let releventDistance = 200;
let unitCount = 5000;

//new unit function creates a unit in a random position on the map
function newUnit(id){
    let newUnit = {};
    newUnit.id = id;
    newUnit.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*mapWidth);
    newUnit.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*mapHeight);
    //this array of 'relevent' neigbours is the collection of other units close enough to interact with
    newUnit.neighbours = [];
    return newUnit;
}

//simple distance test
function distance (unit1, unit2){
    let dx = unit1.x - unit2.x;
    let dy = unit1.y - unit2.y;
    return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);    
}

//collection of units
var myUnits = [];

//populate the units
for (let i =0; i<unitCount; i++){
  myUnits.push(newUnit(i));
}
console.log(unitCount + " units created");

//complete a full-scan with a nested foreach
let timeStamp1 = new Date();
myUnits.forEach(unit => {
    myUnits.forEach(unit2 => {
        //don't test a unit against itself
        if(unit.id != unit2.id){
            let unitDist = distance(unit, unit2);
            if (unitDist <= releventDistance){
               unit.neighbours.push({unit : unit2, distance : unitDist});
            }
        }
    })
})

//print results
console.log((new Date() - timeStamp1) + "ms: to complete bruteforce fullscan");

//print average number of neigbours
let totalNeighbourCount = 0;
myUnits.forEach(myUnit => {totalNeighbourCount += myUnit.neighbours.length});
console.log(Math.floor(totalNeighbourCount/myUnits.length) + ": average number of neighbours");
```

Comment: Use a `for(const unit of myUnits) {}` instead of `myUnits.forEach(unit => {})` it will cut the time in half

Comment: That's an interesting observation and I agree it helps! Can you give a little explanation as to why?

Comment: This hint is not changing the O(n) complexity, however computing square root is an expensive operation (at these levels). Is better to pre-compute only once `releventDistanceSquared = releventDistance*releventDistance;` and then use `function squaredDistance (unit1, unit2)` to compare with.

Comment: That's a reasonable optimisation with no downside, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate only from the index plus one for the inner loop and avoid visiting already visited pairs.

This approach requires to add the pair to each neighbor.

```js
//create the world
let mapWidth = 5000;
let mapHeight = 2000;
let releventDistance = 200;
let unitCount = 5000;

//new unit function creates a unit in a random position on the map
function newUnit(id){
    let newUnit = {};
    newUnit.id = id;
    newUnit.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*mapWidth);
    newUnit.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*mapHeight);
    //this array of 'relevent' neigbours is the collection of other units close enough to interact with
    newUnit.neighbours = [];
    return newUnit;
}

//simple distance test
function distance (unit1, unit2){
    let dx = unit1.x - unit2.x;
    let dy = unit1.y - unit2.y;
    return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);    
}

//collection of units
var myUnits = [];

//populate the units
for (let i =0; i<unitCount; i++){
    myUnits.push(newUnit(i));
}
console.log(unitCount + " units created");

let timeStamp1 = new Date();

for (let i = 0, l1 = myUnits.length - 1; i < l1; i++) {
    const unit = myUnits[i];
    for (let j = i + 1, l2 = myUnits.length; j < l2; j++) {
        const unit2 = myUnits[j];
        let unitDist  = distance(unit, unit2);
        if (unitDist <= releventDistance) {
            unit2.neighbours.push({ unit: unit, distance: unitDist });
            unit.neighbours.push({ unit: unit2, distance: unitDist });
        }
    }
}

//print results
console.log((new Date() - timeStamp1) + "ms: to complete bruteforce fullscan");

//print average number of neigbours
let totalNeighbourCount = 0;
myUnits.forEach(myUnit => {totalNeighbourCount += myUnit.neighbours.length});
console.log(Math.floor(totalNeighbourCount/myUnits.length) + ": average number of neighbours");
```